# Does Kinesis Firehose support Update operation on OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose, opensearch

I'm designing a data indexing pipeline to OpenSearch using Firehose(using the built-in transformation lambda), like : `data source ----(putRecordBatch)----> firehose ---(Lambda transformation)--> OpenSearch`

New data added to data store will be indexed via this flow in near-real time. There is requirement of both creating new documents, and doing partial update on existing documents(ie, updating select attributes of a specified document id).

Does Firehose integration with OpenSearch support Upsert(Update if document is seen in OpenSearch, else insert)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell that is not possible.

I've found this question: [How can AWS Kinesis Firehose lambda send update and delete requests to ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71326537/) which confirms my thought.